# Error in backend: invalid llvm.linker.options building SourceKit-LSP on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: swift, linux, ubuntu, clang, sourcekit

I am following [this](https://medium.com/@pvzig/swift-development-with-visual-studio-code-on-linux-99cac3918582) tutorial in order to get Visual Studio Code and [SourceKit-LSP](https://github.com/apple/sourcekit-lsp) integrated on Ubuntu 18.10, however, I got stuck at building sourcekit-lsp project.

The error I'm getting:

```
fatal error
: 
error in backend: invalid llvm.linker.options


clang: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
clang version 7.0.0-3 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
```

I'm not sure if its relevant, but after typing `Swift` in the console I get the following errors:

```
error: ld-2.28.so 0xffffffff0005f117: adding range [0x14167-0x141ca) which has a base that is less than the function's low PC 0x148c0. Please file a bug and attach the file at the start of this error message
error: ld-2.28.so 0xffffffff0005f117: adding range [0x141e0-0x141e6) which has a base that is less than the function's low PC 0x148c0. Please file a bug and attach the file at the start of this error message
error: ld-2.28.so 0xffffffff0005f184: adding range [0x14167-0x141ca) which has a base that is less than the function's low PC 0x148c0. Please file a bug and attach the file at the start of this error message
error: ld-2.28.so 0xffffffff0005f184: adding range [0x141e0-0x141e6) which has a base that is less than the function's low PC 0x148c0. Please file a bug and attach the file at the start of this error message
Welcome to Swift version 5.0-dev (LLVM b10ce3d642, Clang c1979d7668, Swift 94b167db75).
Type :help for assistance.
```

I would appreciate if anyone could give me a hint how to solve the problem. The only thing that came up to my mind was reinstalling clang, but it hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: *`error in backend: invalid llvm.linker.options`* says the problem is with your linker options. To state the obvious, you should tell us what linker options you used.

Comment: I have no idea how to change linker options, so I assume default options were used. If anyone else struggles with this problem - I just ran Ubuntu 18.04 from a pendrive in live mode, built sourceKit-LSP and used compiled binaries on Ubuntu 18.10 and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an llvm bug (https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39743). See workaround here: https://forums.swift.org/t/error-while-trying-to-build-sourcekit-lsp-on-linux/18138/2